# Accidentally uninstalled Bluetooth from Elementary OS Loki.

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

Reinstalled it, but it doesn't work, and icon doesn't appear on the top dock

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run `sudo modprobe btusb` on the command line if you uninstalled and disabled the kernel module.

For example running `sudo lsmod | grep blue` gives me the result:

```
bluetooth             540672  41 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
```

You can check if you have the above kernel modules available, and if not, you might need them, depending on your hardware setup.

You can disable them again with `sudo modprobe -r btusb` as an example. Let me know if you get it working. It can be quite fiddly and sometimes I need to remove `btusb` and add it again to revive bluetooth after standby (not always), and if bluetooth is completely failing, you often need to shutdown and power off completely, not just restart to revive it.